# Directive Title AngularJS not it works

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wonder of you with experience in angularJS, it is possible to create a directive for the title of the page. title that he comes from a database and am bringing through the ng-model. however every time I create a directive for him to carry this title for the application to function, as if he could not run the directive.

```
<!-- my index.html -->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" id="ng-app" ng-app="app-work">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <titlepage></titlepage>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    </html>


<!-- my directive -->
    app.directive('titlepage', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
             templateUrl: 'partials/directives/titlepage.html',
                scope: {
                    titleapp: '='
                }
        };
    }])



<!-- my pagetitle.html -->
<title ng-model="app.title"></title>
```

Comment: In your html I am not seeing the ng-app attribute?

Comment: sorry, but exist that I had forgotten to put in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ng-model` you should interpolation.

```
<!-- my index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" id="ng-app" ng-app="app-work">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <titlepage></titlepage>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>


<!-- my directive -->
app.directive('titlepage', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
         templateUrl: 'partials/directives/titlepage.html',
            scope: {
                titleapp: '='
            }
    };
}])

 <!-- my pagetitle.html --> 
 <title>{{app.title}}</title>
```